# sql server assistance with cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a question about cursors

The question is : for all orders which are due in August 2008 show its details in the following format

```
OrderNumber (n items) due DueDate is Status
```

This is the expected output

```
SO75123(3 items) due Aug 12 2008 12:00AM is Shipped
```

I have this so far

```
DECLARE
    @salesOrderID INT,
    @salesOrderNum NVARCHAR(20), 
    @dueDate DATETIME, 
    @status NVARCHAR(20), 
    @totalDue MONEY, 
    @numDetail INT,
    @count INT = 0;

DECLARE salesReportCursor CURSOR 
FOR
    SELECT Count(S.salesOrderID),p.SalesOrderNumber,p.Duedate, status =
        CASE  when p.status =1 THEN 'In Process'
            when p.status =2  THEN ' Approved'
            when p.status =3 THEN ' Backordered'
            when p.status =4 THEN ' Rejected'
            when p.status =5 THEN ' Shipped'
        END
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader p, Sales.SalesOrderDetail s
    WHERE p.SalesOrderID=s.SalesOrderID AND  P.DueDate >= '2008' AND p.DueDate < '2009'
    Group by p.SalesOrderNumber,p.Duedate,status
    ORDER BY SalesOrderNumber DESC
```

I'm supposed to get around 360 rows but I'm getting like 1400. Please tell me whats wrong in my where clause that's causing the error.

My picture of the database is http://www.2shared.com/photo/h2-jMQyP/AdventureWorks2008.html

Comment: Three things: 1) you should probably flag this "homework" (if it is), 2) you should probably be doing an "inner join" between SalesOrderHeader and SalesOrderDetail ... and 3) maybe the problem is in your "where", or maybe you should specify *fewer* columns in your "group by"

Comment: And you're not limiting the results to orders due in August 2008.

Comment: @paulsm4  this aint homework im practising for my test which is next week

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need assistance with cursors tsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969263/need-assistance-with-cursors-tsql)

Comment: **WHY** on earth would you want to do this with a cursor?? Cursors are evil, cursor smell bad, cursors are to be **avoided** wherever possible - and here it's really **trivial** to avoid a cursor!

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple query - and you're done - no messy cursors or anyhting like that needed!! I'm getting 370 rows from this:

```
SELECT 
    Count(s.SalesOrderID), 
    p.SalesOrderNumber,
    p.DueDate, 
    OrderStatus =
    CASE  
        WHEN p.Status = 1 THEN 'In Process'
        WHEN p.Status = 2  THEN ' Approved'
        WHEN p.Status = 3 THEN ' Backordered'
        WHEN p.Status = 4 THEN ' Rejected'
        WHEN p.Status = 5 THEN ' Shipped'
    END
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader p
INNER JOIN  
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail s ON p.SalesOrderID = s.SalesOrderID 
WHERE 
    -- restrict "DueDate" to between Aug 1st, 2008, and Aug 31st, 2008
    p.DueDate >= '20080801' AND p.DueDate < '20080901'
GROUP BY 
    p.SalesOrderNumber, p.DueDate, p.Status
ORDER BY 
    SalesOrderNumber DESC
```